# How to make css picked using javascript on a page the css style for all pages

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript to change the css of my web page and I am trying to figure out how to make which ever css is picked, the css for all other pages on my site.

Here is my code:

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dash4.css">
<script>
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
</script>
 <button class="settings" onclick="swapStyleSheet('dash4.css')">    COMFORTABLE</button>
        <button class="settings" onclick="swapStyleSheet('dash4_minimal.css')">MINIMAL</button>
```

Comment: "I am trying to figure out how to make which ever css is picked" - can yo make it clear

Comment: ^ agreed, I believe you should say: "I am trying to figure out how to make which ever style sheet is picked by the user get applied to my entire website"

Comment: Perhaps use [a cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to set and retrieve which stylesheet should be used for a given page onload?

Comment: Second the cookie idea. Why not use a more permanent persistence layer though? Store the pick for a given session and then include that in the next request?

Comment: Hi Garrett, how would you recommend I store the pick and then request it?

Answer (score 0):

just put your script before the closing tag of your body
and with jquery write

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-id").click(function(){
        $("#pagestyle").attr("href",sheet);
    });
});
```

Comment: it looks like you just re wrote the code I already have. I am asking what code I can add to each page that will set the css on that page to match which css the user chose from my code above that is on a different page. Does this make sense?